# ASP.Net MVC AND WPF wioth probably Windows 8 Phone

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm, windows-phone

I am currently developing an application that utlises telerik ORM tools to manage access to a back end database. On top of this layer I am implementing a Business Layer(domain) containing the real world objects that represent my application model.
So far so good.

The issue I have now is one of serious confusion. I will be developing a ASP.Net MVC web site that forms the main hub of my application. In addition to this I have the requirement to create a WPF application that implements some integration into the desktop and lastly I would like to implement a Windows 8 phone app containing a subset of the ASP.Net website functionality but that will also implement some of the WPF functionality.

The problem is I would like to keep the application as simple as possible and maintain a high level of code reuse. Ideally I don't want to implement multiple business layers but I'm not sure of what architectural patterns would be best used? I think adding some kind of service - be it REST, Web services, WEB API or something on top of the business layer and then dealing with each UI technology independently will be the way to go but I thought I'd ask for opinions and advice before I head down a route and end up back tracking?

Answer (score 0):

You could use WCF or Web API as the layer that sits on top of your business layer.  If you're looking to use RESTful api, then the new Web API is a good place to start.

If you take a look at these tutorials, they should help: http://www.asp.net/web-api/samples

Your client applications would then call into these API's to communicate with your business / data layer.